# MySQL how use correlated query in join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, correlated-subquery

I found, that MySql do not support correlated queries in joins. Is it possible to rewrite provided (simplyfied) query keeping it logic?

```
SELECT *
FROM tableX AS x
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT y.xFK, COUNT(y.id) AS y_count
    FROM tableY AS y
    WHERE y.xFK = x.id
    GROUP BY y.xFK
) AS sub
ON sub.xFK = x.id
WHERE sub.y_count > 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
  x.*, COUNT(y.ID) AS y_count
FROM tableX x
  LEFT JOIN tableY y
    ON y.xFK = x.ID
GROUP BY
  x.ID
HAVING
  y_count > 1
```